# Programming access Windows network shared folders

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Windows shared folders like these:
[image]

Actually you can write file operation code just like in the local,

```
#include <filesystem>
using namespace std;
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    fs::path fromPath = "D:\\temp\\test.zip";
    fs::path toPath = R"(\\127.0.0.1\ProgramData\test.zip)";
    std::error_code ec;
    bool b = fs::copy_file(fromPath, toPath, ec);
    cout << (b ? "OK" : ec.message()) << endl;

    std::ofstream fout(R"(\\127.0.0.1\ProgramData\test.txt)");
    fout << "abc";
}
```

except you need to login to the target computer first:

[image]

Unfortunately, this step is manual. Can I write some code do such work (login) automatically? Of course, all the shared folders and user / permissions are pre-settled.

Comment: [WNetAddConnection2W](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnetwk/nf-winnetwk-wnetaddconnection2w)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you could try to use [WNetAddConnection2 function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnetwk/nf-winnetwk-wnetaddconnection2a) to make a connection to a network resource.

```
NETRESOURCE resource;
resource.dwType=RESOURCETYPE_DISK;
resource.lpLocalName=NULL;
resource.lpRemoteName=L"……"; //remote network name
resource.lpProvider=NULL;
DWORD result = WNetAddConnection2(&resource, lpPassword, lpUserName, CONNECT_TEMPORARY);
```